# Tensorflow How to apply batch normalization to inference

Tags: tensorflow, normalization

Hi. I am quite new to tf and the question is how to apply the batch normalization to inference. I applied batch normalization with tensorflow during training and testing. The code is as following and as you can see, I treat training and testing with different mean and var value. Now the training is completed and I want to apply the model to practice. Such as use a demo load the ckpt file and test just one example. In this case, how can I normalize this one case? Is there any approach I can save the mean and var of BN after each epoch of training and restore later? Thank you very very much!

```
    fc_mean, fc_var = tf.nn.moments(
            input,
            axes=[0], 
        )
        scale = tf.Variable(tf.ones([out_size]))
        shift = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([out_size]))
        epsilon = 0.001
        ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.5)
        def mean_var_with_update():
            ema_apply_op = ema.apply([fc_mean, fc_var])
            with tf.control_dependencies([ema_apply_op]):
                return tf.identity(fc_mean), tf.identity(fc_var)
        mean, var = tf.cond(train_phase,
                             mean_var_with_update,
                             lambda: (ema.average(fc_mean),
                                      ema.average(fc_var)
                                      )
                             )
        input_BN = tf.nn.batch_normalization(input, mean, var, shift, scale, epsilon)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but do you guys think this gonna be right? I saved the shift(offset) and scale, which yield during training. And when I need to apply the model to practice, I just use shift and scale to replace the mean and var.And set the shift and var of test case as zero.

```
    if not test:
        input_BN = tf.nn.batch_normalization(input, mean, var, shift, scale, epsilon)
    else:
        input_BN = tf.nn.batch_normalization(input, shift, scale, 0, 0, epsilon)
```

Comment: Sorry I am a little bit messed now. In the paper, it says by setting scale = sqrt(var), shift=mean, we could recover the original activations. So during training by tensorflow, what would the value of scale and shift be after the model well converged?